# how to hide the previous form when the present form is being loaded

Tags: c#, winforms

In C sharp win forms,
not using MDI, m creating multiple forms 
i wish to hide the previous form while loading a new form on a button's click 
i write the following code to achieve the purpose but the previous form still remains visible, kindly help!!
here's the code...

```
private void btnEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f3 = new EmployeeLogIn();
    f3.Show();
    Form id = new Login();
    id.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're hiding a newly-created form. You need to get the reference to the previous form by either passing it into the current form, or using a static property.

EDIT: actually I think this is what you wanted to do:

```
private void btnEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f3 = new EmployeeLogIn();
    f3.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only continue when the form is loaded, so when the `f3.Show()` statement is finished.

Consider showing the `f3` form in a new thread.